# how to pass argument to constructor on library load?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, constructor, shared-libraries

I am trying to create a shared library in Linux. How can I pass an argument to function my_load() when library is loaded? In my C application, I make a call to test_func() then it automatically executes my_load() first before the called function then lastly it executes my_unload()

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_load(int argc, char *argv[]);
void __attribute__ ((destructor)) my_unload(void);
void test_func(void);

void my_load(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("my_load: %d\n", argc);
}

void my_unload(void) {
printf("my_unload\n");
}

void test_func(void) {
printf("test_func()\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dynamic library can always read [`/proc/self/cmdline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to see what the command-line parameters used to execute the current executable are. `example.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static char **get_argv(int *const argcptr)
{
    char  **argv;
    char   *data = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;    /* Allocated to data */
    size_t  used = 0;
    size_t  argc, i;
    ssize_t bytes;
    int     fd;

    if (argcptr)
        *argcptr = 0;

    do {
        fd = open("/proc/self/cmdline", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1)
        return NULL;

    while (1) {

        if (used >= size) {
            char *old_data = data;
            size = (used | 4095) + 4096;
            data = realloc(data, size + 1);
            if (data == NULL) {
                free(old_data);
                close(fd);
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        do {
            bytes = read(fd, data + used, size - used);
        } while (bytes == (ssize_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (bytes < (ssize_t)0) {
            free(data);
            close(fd);
            errno = EIO;
            return NULL;

        } else
        if (bytes == (ssize_t)0)
            break;

        else
            used += bytes;
    }

    if (close(fd)) {
        free(data);
        errno = EIO;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Let's be safe and overallocate one pointer here. */
    argc = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < used; i++)
        if (data[i] == '\0')
            argc++;

    /* Reallocate to accommodate both pointers and data. */
    argv = realloc(data, (argc + 1) * sizeof (char *) + used + 1);
    if (argv == NULL) {
        free(data);
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }
    data = (char *)(argv + argc + 1);
    memmove(data, argv, used);

    /* In case the input lacked a trailing NUL byte. */
    data[used] = '\0';

    /* Assign the pointers. */
    argv[0] = data;
    argc = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < used; i++)
        if (data[i] == '\0')
            argv[++argc] = data + i + 1;
    /* Final pointer points to past data. Make it end the array. */
    argv[argc] = NULL;

    if (argcptr)
        *argcptr = (int)argc;

    return argv;
}

/* Example standard error functions, that avoid the use of stdio.h.
*/
static void wrerr(const char *p)
{
    if (p != NULL) {
        const char *const q = p + strlen(p);
        ssize_t           n;

        while (p < q) {
            n = write(STDERR_FILENO, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1)
                return;
            else
            if (errno != EINTR)
                return;
        }
    }
}
static void wrerrint(const int i)
{
    char          buffer[32];
    char         *p = buffer + sizeof buffer;
    unsigned int  u;

    if (i < 0)
        u = (unsigned int)(-i);
    else
        u = (unsigned int)i;

    *(--p) = '\0';
    do {
        *(--p) = '0' + (u % 10U);
        u /= 10U;
    } while (u > 0U);
    if (i < 0)
        *(--p) = '-';

    wrerr(p);
}



static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void init(void)
{
    int    argc, i, saved_errno;
    char **argv;

    saved_errno = errno;

    argv = get_argv(&argc);
    if (argv == NULL) {
        const char *const errmsg = strerror(errno);
        wrerr("libexample.so: get_argv() failed: ");
        wrerr(errmsg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        errno = saved_errno;
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        wrerr("libexample.so: argv[");
        wrerrint((int)i);
        wrerr("] = '");
        wrerr(argv[i]);
        wrerr("'\n");
    }

    free(argv);

    errno = saved_errno;
    return;
}
```

Compile using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared example.c -ldl -Wl,-soname,libexample.so -o libexample.so
```

and test using e.g.

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libexample.so /bin/echo foo bar baz baaz
```

(Note that plain `echo` is a shell built-in, and you need to execute another binary like `/bin/echo` to load the preload library.)

However, most dynamic libraries take arguments in environment variables instead; for example, `YOURLIB_MEM` for some memory size hint, or `YOURLIB_DEBUG` for enabling verbose debugging output during runtime.

(My example code does not use stdio.h output, because not all binaries use it, especially if written in some other language. Instead, the `wrerr()` and `wrerrint()` are small stupid helper functions that use low-level unistd.h I/O to write directly to standard error; this always works, and causes minimal side effects at run time.)

Questions?

Comment: This of course assumes `/proc` is mounted, which isn't always the case.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: True. However, you cannot assume a program will work without `/proc` mounted in Linux anyway. You lose quite a bit of functionality without `/proc`, including some glibc functions like [`fexecve()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fexecve.3.html), and utilities like `pidof` stop working. It's not that important, though: as I said, *"most dynamic libraries [should] take arguments in environment variables"*, and that does not rely on `/proc` in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

`__attribute__((constructor))` simply doesn't support this.

There doesn't seem to be any reason you can't just call `my_load(argc, argv)` at the very beginning of `main()`.

You can use `atexit` to register a function to be called when your program exits normally, or returns from main.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    my_load(argc, argv);
    atexit(my_unload);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to pass arguments to gcc constructor and destructor functions. The best you can do is to use global variables.

In you example, you could try :

In main :

```
int Argc;
char *Argv[];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Argc = argc;
    Argv = argv;
    ...
}
```

In shared library :

```
extern int Argc;
...
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_load();
...
void my_load() {
printf("my_load: %d\n", Argc);
}
```

But anyway, it can only work if you explicitely load the shared library through `dlopen`. It it is directly referenced at link time, the constructor function will be called before first instruction in main and you will always find the original value or 0 in `Argc`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an oldie here but I just tested this on both Linux and Mac OS:

```
$ gcc -x c -o test_prog -
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_load(int argc, char *argv[]);
void __attribute__ ((destructor)) my_unload(void);
void test_func(void);

void my_load(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("my_load: %d\n", argc);
}

void my_unload(void) {
printf("my_unload\n");
}

void test_func(void) {
printf("test_func()\n");
}

int main() { return 0; }
```

And it prints this result on both systems:

```
$ ./test_prog foo bar baz
my_load: 4
my_unload
```

In order for it to work as a shared library I did have to add the linker option `-Wl,--no-gc-sections` because it otherwise aggressively removed the constructor & destructor.  But otherwise yeah this works already.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t use the `__attribute__ ((constructor))` syntax, but if you specify a custom `_init` function, you can do so:

```c
// foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
void my_constructor(int argc, char**argv) {
  printf("my_constructor init: %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

To do so you need to pass `ld -init my_constructor` or `gcc -Wl,-init,my_constructor`, e.g.

```
gcc foo.c -shared -o libfoo.so -Wl,-init,my_constructor
```