# sigprocmask not blocking unwanted signal

Tags: c, linux, kernel, signals, handler

I'm currently modifying perf in Linux source tree to implement a tool that I need.

perf originally has a signal handler installed(handler for SIGUSR2) but I want to extend its functionality by handling two signals(SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2)

As shown below, **the kernel (not a user process)** sends the two signals consecutively.

```
    asmlinkage long sys_pt_signal_perf(void) //new syscall No.500
    {
            return (long)pt_signal_perf_wrapper();
    }

    int pt_signal_perf_wrapper(void)
    {
            if(signal_perf(2) != -1) { //SIGUSR2
                    /* Some dummy loop */
                    signal_perf(1); //SIGUSR1

                    printk(KERN_EMERG "Marker chunk : %d\n", j);
                    printk(KERN_EMERG "[SEMAPHORE LOCK] Marker Chunk\n");
                    pt_down_interruptible(&decode_semaphore); //perf user process unlocks this semaphore lock
                    printk(KERN_EMERG "Decoding for this syscall seems to be finished\n");

                    return 1;
            }
            else {
                    return 0;
            }
    }
    EXPORT_SYMBOL(pt_signal_perf_wrapper);

    int signal_perf(int sig_type)
    {
            int signal_to_send;
            if(sig_type == 1)
                    signal_to_send = SIGUSR1;
            else
                    signal_to_send = SIGUSR2;


            if(!perf_pid) {
                    return -1;
            }
            if(!target_pid) {
                    return -1;
            }

            struct siginfo info;
            memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
            info.si_signo = signal_to_send;
            info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;
            info.si_int = SI_USER;

            struct task_struct *t = find_task_by_vpid(perf_pid);
            if(!t) {
                    printk(KERN_EMERG "No task struct for %d!\n", perf_pid);
                    return -1;
            }
            int send_sig_info_result = send_sig_info(signal_to_send, &info, t);
            if(send_sig_info_result < 0)
                    printk(KERN_EMERG "KKM : Error sending signal!!\n");
            else
                    printk(KERN_EMERG "KKM : sending signal successful!!\n");

            return (long)perf_pid;
    }
```

The perf, the signal receipient, runs as a user process.

```
    static sigset_t pt_sigset;
```

... (in main function)

```
    signal(SIGUSR2, snapshot_sig_handler);
    signal(SIGUSR1, snapshot_sig_handler);

    /* set pt_sigset to block SIGUSR1/2 when they are being processed */
    sigemptyset(&pt_sigset);
    if(sigaddset(&pt_sigset, SIGUSR1) == -1) {
            pr_err("sigaddset for SIGUSR1 returned -1\n");
            return -1;
    }
    if(sigaddset(&pt_sigset, SIGUSR2) == -1) {
            pr_err("sigaddset for SIGUSR2 returned -1\n");
            return -1;
    }
```

in signal handler, when a signal(either SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2) is received , it blocks the both SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 signals using sigprocmask.

```
    static void snapshot_sig_handler(int sig __maybe_unused)
    {
            pr_err("Blocking the two signals\n");
            if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &pt_sigset, NULL) == -1) {
                    pr_err("sigprocmask returned with error\n");
            }

            if(sig == SIGUSR2) {
                    pr_err("SIG_HANDLER from a non-marker chunk\n");
            }
            else if(sig == SIGUSR1) {
                    pr_err("SIG_HANDLER from a marker chunk\n");
            }
            else {
                    pr_err("NOT A VALID SIGNAL!\n");
                    return;
            }

            /* Real operation which is omitted here */
    }
```

Unblocking the two signals is not shown but definitely is there.

But when I actually run the code, there are some cases where the signal handler function is called even when the two signals are unblocked. (like below)

```
Blocking the two signals
SIG_HANDLER from a non-marker chunk
Blocking the two signals
SIG_HANDLER from a marker chunk
Unblocking the two signals
Unblocking the two signals
```

It seems as if blocking of the two signals never even work, although sigprocmask() doesn't return with error.

Is this because the signal is sent from a higher privilege?(kernel->user) Unlike most cases where signal transactions are done between two user processes?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: AFAICS, `pr_err(...)` is a macro evaluating to `fprintf(stderr,...)`. Since `fprintf()` is not [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), the order of your outputs might just be an artefact of that. You could try using my [`wrerr()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28030139/1475978) instead; it is async-signal-safe, but takes a fixed string (and not a format with parameters) -- but since you only print a fixed string anyway, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Don't use `signal` use `sigaction` in which you can control signal blocking on signal delivery. In your code, there can be race condition, means that signal can be delivered while in between `pr_err` and call to `sigprocmask`. This is why `signal` function is considered as obsolete or unreliable.

Comment: @NominalAnimal wow never though of that factor in comprehending this undesired behavior.. I'll definitely try using wrerr() right away. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Actually, I've already tried using sigaction instead of signal but things were the same. But maybe I have to look into the race condition a little more throughly because I haven't until reading your comment. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Just thinking aloud: `sigprocmask()` is async-signal-safe, and modifies the mask for the current thread. While the above scheme (with `sigaction()` and `.sa_mask` containing both `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`) looks sane, I suspect that having a dedicated thread looping on [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) (with both signals blocked in the main thread(s)) would be more robust, and easier to understand/maintain. For all cases of *sequential signals* I've encountered before (I've used realtime signals with integer payloads) it was practically necessary.